# Sumif in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, sumifs

Might be a silly question but I just got stuck.

So what I would like to do is the following.
If number in AO5 is more then or equal to 45 than time by 0.4 if less then 45 than minus 4.6 and time by 0.2 and add and time the rest of the cells (which is 6,7,8,9,10,11) with 0.4 and add and time AO12 with 10.

Im using the below at the moment
=SUMIF((AO5-4.6)*0.2+(AO6+AO7+AO8+AO9+AO10+AO11)*0.4+(AO12*10),">0")
so at the moment it does the first with 0.2 no matter what. so that's what I would like to change to for the above and below 45 thing I wrote first

I would really appreciate the help. I hope it make sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the IF() function, not the SUMIF()

```
=IF(A2 >=45, A2*.4, (A2-4.25)*.2)
```

Comment: I am having an issue. If I use as you wrote it shows -0.92 everywhere where is no entry. I f I use it as =IFs(GJ5 >= 45, GJ5*0.4, (GJ5-4.6)*0.2,0) then it just shows 0 and never take it into count the first cell in calculation. Could you help me with this please?